# How to make mouseover event work multiple elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, addeventlistener, mouseover

I'm trying to make some images rotate in their place when the mouse is over them but I've tried various methods and none seem to work. :(
I don't know if the methods I've tried don't work because the mouseover event doesn't bubble up or if I should change it to mouseenter.
Help please!
This is my code:

```js
document.querySelector(".images").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    var activeAnimation = document.querySelector(".images");
    activeAnimation.classList.add("principalanimation");
    setTimeout(function() {
      activeAnimation.classList.remove("principalanimation");
    }, 1000);
  });
```

```css
.principalanimation {
  animation-name: rotate1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="image_box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <a href="https://classroom.google.com/u/1/w/NTI1OTMwNjM3NDc1/t/all?hl=es" target="blank">
            <img src="images/hp.jpeg" class="img-fluid images" alt="">
          </a>
          <h3 class="feature-titles">Harry Potter</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="image_box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <a href="https://classroom.google.com/u/1/w/NTI1OTMwNjM3NDc1/t/all?hl=es" target="blank">
            <img src="images/1d.jpeg" class="img-fluid images" alt="">
          </a>
          <h3 class="feature-titles">One Direction</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="image_box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <a href="https://www1.cuevana3.vc/13780/bo-burnham-inside" target="blank">
            <img src="images/bo.jpeg" class="img-fluid images" alt="">
          </a>
          <h3 class="feature-titles">Bo Burnham</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="image_box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <a href="https://classroom.google.com/u/1/w/NTI1OTMwNjM3NDc1/t/all?hl=es" target="blank">
            <img src="images/hungie.jpeg" class="img-fluid images" alt="">
          </a>
          <h3 class="feature-titles">The Hunger Games</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="image_box col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <a href="https://www.pelisplus2.io/pelicula/entrevista-con-el-vampiro/" target="blank">
            <img src="images/intervampire.jpeg" class="img-fluid images" alt="">
          </a>
          <h3 class="feature-titles">Interview with the Vampire</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
```